# gnuplot macro dollar sign substitution

Tags: macros, gnuplot

In Gnuplot 4.6.p3, when I call a script that choses which column I should plot from a file, through

```
call 'FitModes.gnp' 12 "0.95" 1 "-50"
```

with (the trouble part of) 'FitModes.gnp' being :

```
c(x)= x==1?'using 3:(abs($$5)):6': x==2?'using 3:(abs($$7)):8': x==3?'using 3:(abs($$9)):10':0    
column = c($2)
#print to check the value of this variable
print "column=",column

p "th$0/b$1/m$3/Data_$0-$1-$3.txt" @column t 'Data' w yerrorlines pt 7 lc @cblue
```

which gives me the "Invalid expression" output:

```
 gnuplot> call 'FitModes.gnp' "12" 0.95 1 "-50"
 column=using 3:(abs($5)):6

 gnuplot> p "th12/b0.95/m-50/Data_12-0.95--50.txt" using 3:(abs()):6 t 'Data' w yerrorlines pt 7 lc rgbcolor "#0083AB"
```

due to the absence of column number in the `abs()` function despite the `$5` being there in the `column` variable. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `column` function instead of referring to the columns with the shortcut  `$...`:

```
c(x)= x==1?'using 3:(abs(column(5))):6': x==2?'using 3:(abs(column(7))):8': x==3?'using 3:(abs(column(9))):10':0    
column = c($2)
```